# Can I change NetTrain's error handling?

Tags: warning-messages, neural-networks

The `NetTrain` function to train a neural network often takes several hours to complete. But if there's an error during that time, it simply aborts and returns `$Failed`, so hours of training progress are lost.

I'd prefer if `NetTrain` would just print a message for recoverable errors and continue training. Is there a way to achieve that?

For example, after several hours of training `NetTrain` just aborted with this error message:

> RandomVariate::array: The array dimensions {104,2143} given in position 2 of RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-0.02,0.02}],{104,2143}] should be a list of non-negative machine-sized integers giving the dimensions for the result.

Since `{104,2143}` *is* a list of non-negative machine-sized integers, and the same line of code with the same arguments worked a million times before, I'd say this is a rare bug in `RandomVariate`. I don't see how I could fix or even reproduce it, so I'd rather just ignore it and try again.

Alternatively: Is there a way to catch *all* errors that might happen in my generator function, and simply try the same code again?

Comment: Have you seen `TrainingProgessCheckpointing`?

Comment: @Sascha: I hadn't seen this, thanks. I'll definitely use that for future overnight training sessions. Then I wouldn't have lost the training progress until the error happened. Still would have wasted the PC time after the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah that's kinda annoying.

For situations where your data is a generator, and you expect a message to be issued when the failure happens (e.g. your `RandomVariate` example) this should robustify your training:

```
$generator = Function[...]; 
$robustGenerator = Function[$fallback = Check[$generator[#], $fallback]];
NetTrain[net, $robustGenerator, ...]
```

This will just re-use the last batch if a message occurs during the call to the actual generator.

Ideally we'd handle this more directly in `NetTrain`, of course.